# Capturing R6025 pure virtual call

Tags: c++, windows, minidump, dbghelp

I currently capture MiniDumps of unhandled exceptions using `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` however at times I am getting "R6025: pure virtual function".

I understand how a pure virtual function call happens I am just wondering if it is possible to capture them so I can create a MiniDump at that point.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to catch all crashes you have to do more than just: SetUnhandledExceptionFilter

I would also set the abort handler, the purecall handler, unexpected, terminate, and invalid parameter handler.

```
#include <signal.h>

inline void signal_handler(int)
{
    terminator();
}

inline void terminator() 
{
    int*z = 0; *z=13; 
}

inline void __cdecl invalid_parameter_handler(const wchar_t *, const wchar_t *, const wchar_t *, unsigned int, uintptr_t)
{
   terminator();
}
```

And in your main put this:

```
 signal(SIGABRT, signal_handler);
 _set_abort_behavior(0, _WRITE_ABORT_MSG|_CALL_REPORTFAULT);

 set_terminate( &terminator );
 set_unexpected( &terminator );
 _set_purecall_handler( &terminator );
 _set_invalid_parameter_handler( &invalid_parameter_handler );
```

The above will send all crashes to your unhandled exception handler.

Answer (score 12):

See [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99552/where-do-pure-virtual-function-call-crashes-come-from#100555) to the question [where do “pure virtual function call” crashes come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99552/where-do-pure-virtual-function-call-crashes-come-from).

> To help with debugging these kinds of
>   problems you can, in various versions
>   of MSVC, replace the runtime library's
>   purecall handler. You do this by
>   providing your own function with this
>   signature:

```
int __cdecl _purecall(void)
```

> and
>   linking it before you link the runtime
>   library. This gives YOU control of
>   what happens when a purecall is
>   detected. Once you have control you
>   can do something more useful than the
>   standard handler. I have a handler
>   that can provide a stack trace of
>   where the purecall happened; see here:
>   http://www.lenholgate.com/archives/000623.html
>   for more details.
>
> (Note you can also call
>   `_set_purecall_handler()` to install your handler in some versions of
>   MSVC).

So, in your purecall handler, make your minidump.

Answer (score -2):

Try defining the offending pure virtual. There is nothing in the C++ rules that prohibit you from defining a pure virtual, and you can use this for a number of reasons, the least of which is getting a backtrace on the call. The only caviat is the definition must be outside the declaration (`virtual void bla() = 0 { }` is not valid).