# How to customize uncaught exception termination behavior?

Tags: c++, exception, terminate

In `g++` and `clang++` (in Linux at least) the following typical message is shown after an exception is thrown and not catch (uncaught exception):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Bye
```

For example in:

```
#include<stdexcept>
int main(){
  throw std::runtime_error("Bye");
}
```

How do I customize the error message while still having full access to the thrown exception?

The documentation (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/set_unexpected/) mentions `set_unexpected` (and `set_terminate`) but I don't know how the `unexpected_handle` has actual access to the exception being thrown, for example to call `e.what()` or something else.

**Note**: The reason behind this is that I want to customize the message for a more complicated exception class hierarchy that has more information than simple `what()`, and I want to display it if such type exception is thrown (but if a simple `std::exception&` is thrown the default is the same as the typical.

**Note2**: According to the two suggestions so far, "customize uncaught exceptions by catching the exceptions." Will look like what follows in the code. I was wondering if there is a way to do the same without adding a `try-catch` block to *all* `main()` code that I write.

```
#include<stdexcept>
int main() try{
   ....
}catch(std::exception& e){
  std::clog << "terminate called after throwing an instance of '" << typeid(e) << "'\n"
            << "  what(): " << e.what() << '\n'
            << "otherinfo, like current time\n";
}catch(alternative_exception& e){
  std::clog << "terminate called after throwing an instance of '" << typeid(e) << "'\n"
            << "  what(): " << e.what() << '\n'
            << "  where(): " << e.where() << '\n'
            << "  how(): " << e.how() << '\n'
            << "othermember(): " << e.othermember() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at the boost_exception thing. Otherwise, why would you not just try/catch std::exception e and work from there? That's pretty much what the default does in Linux.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774316/c-unhandled-exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from actually catching the exceptions you care about, [`std::set_terminate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate) and [`std::current_exception()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception) (C++11) ought to be enough to do something interesting.

Comment: Thanks, I added an answer based on these tips. It seems I didn't need to use `std::current_exception`.

Answer (score 3):

The hook for customizing the handling of uncaught exceptions is catching the exceptions.

Comment: However there are some cases where you can't do that. Static object constructors, for example.

Comment: @Pete, does it mean also to put a `try-catch` around all `main()` programs? Besides this being annoying, is celtschk a counter example where this doesn't work? (please see my edit).

Comment: @celtschk - function try blocks handle exceptions thrown from constructors.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Only if you are the author of the class and therefore can write the constructor.

Comment: @celtschk - or if you write a derived class that forwards to the constructors of the base type and catches thrown exceptions.

Comment: Of course *that* requires that you are the author of the static variable, and can choose its type yourself.

Comment: @celtschk - the original poster is **not** asserting that he is dealing with an exception thrown from the constructor of a static object that is not part of the code that he is writing. He just doesn't want to write a try block in `main`.

Comment: @PeteBecker, thanks for interpreting my question. Yes, I want to change the default behavior at a single point common to all code (e.g. by including a specific header).

Comment: And the default behaviour is also triggered by an exception escaping from a static constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @JonPurdy (accepted) answer, I experimented with this code that seems to work, at least with gcc 4.7.2 and clang 3.2 in Linux. I have no idea how robust or portable it is (comments welcomed), I tried not to make assumptions about the default terminate handler:

```
#include<stdexcept>
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo> // for typeid

// a special exception, can be an abstract class, here it is concrete class to make the example shorter.
struct debug_exception : std::runtime_error{
    std::string where_;
    debug_exception(std::string what, std::string where) : std::runtime_error(what), where_(where){}
    virtual const char* where() const{return where_.c_str();}
};

std::terminate_handler my_default_terminate;

void my_verbose_terminate_handler(){
    try{
        throw;
    }catch(debug_exception& e){
        std::cerr << "my_verbose_terminate_handler called after throwing an instance of " 
                  << typeid(e).name() << std::endl; // or demangled
        std::cerr << "  what(): "  << e.what()  << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "  where(): " << e.where() << std::endl;
    }catch(...){
        my_default_terminate(); // probably __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler();
    }
}
std::terminate_handler my_improve_terminate(){
    my_default_terminate = std::set_terminate(my_verbose_terminate_handler);
    return my_default_terminate;
}

int main(){
    my_improve_terminate();
//  throw 2; // says the default "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'"
//  throw std::runtime_error("bye"); // says the default "terminate called ... what(): bye"
    throw debug_exception("Bye", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); // says my_verbose_terminate_handler called ... what(): Bye, where(): int main()"
}
```

Now I am experimenting with wrapping all the code in a `class` and call `my_improve_terminate()` before `main` so when including a certain file it becomes the new default.

Comment: Note `typeid(e).name()` is not always particularly legible.

Comment: @aschepler, yes, I should demangle it, just as `__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler` does; I didn't want too make the example too long. Note added.

Comment: btw, I couldn't find the implementation of `__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler`, the default termination handler in gnu's std. Where can I find it? is it a real function that one can look up?