# gcc undefined _cxa_pure_virtual

Tags: gcc, linkage

I have 2 shared object libs and one executable.

1 of the libs that I compile has linkage error: `Undefined _cxa_pure_virtual`.

Why?
Usually we do not need to implement it. Any Ideas?

If I implement it both the libs compile and link OK, but the application that links to both has same linkage issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lib in question is a C++ library and the __cxa_pure_virtual is needed by the C++ runtime. Suggest that you try first linking with g++ command instead of gcc.

Read more under this question: [What is the purpose of cxa pure virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920500/what-is-the-purpose-of-cxa-pure-virtual)