# Debugging R6025 pure virtual function call by breaking in purevirt.c

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008

I have an annoying R6025 error that keeps cropping up. I want to squash it, but I need to find where it's coming from. I want to break on the _purecall function in purevirt.c, but I don't have the symbols for it apparently. I'm using VS2008 SP1. I have set the symbol cache location in Tools -> Options -> Debugging, and I have loaded all the modules it says the app is using when I debug. The closest CRT library I get to purevirt.c is msvcm90d.dll - is this really the right one? It does say the symbols were loaded correctly.

Comment: Can you get the error to occur when running under the debugger?  When I do that, I get a dialog about the 'pure function call' error with the option to Retry to break into the debugger. At that point, the debugger gives a clear stack trace.

Comment: I get the little dialog window, but all it has is "OK" - no retry or anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Please see this [very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/100555/628361): you'll be able to implement your own handler (and break there).

Comment: I tried this; unfortunately the project I have is a class library running in C++/CLI from a C# application. I tried running the code in the earliest point of that class library but it wouldn't work.