# R6205 pure function call error using ATL service template

Tags: c++, atl, virtual-functions

I have a very simple ATL service that implements `CAtlServiceModuleT`. It does not use any virtual functions in the implementation of the service, but obviously the ATL template object does use virtual functions.

I looked through the implementation of the `CAtlServiceModuleT` and it does not appear to define any pure virtual functions, but the template itself is declared using the declspec(novtable) which I don't quite understand.

I understand the basic use cases for what causes pure virtual call errors, but this does not seem to fall into any of those categories, e.g.:

[Where do "pure virtual function call" crashes come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99552/where-do-pure-virtual-function-call-crashes-come-from/100555#100555)

I've written a purecall implementation to try and get a better stack trace, but I have not been able to reproduce this in house.

Where else can this error come from?

Comment: Have debugger stopped at the time of exception or error message and check call stack - you will see where it comes from.

Comment: Again, I've been unable to reproduce this in house, so I need to be a bit more analytical.