# Why is this not a call of a pure virtual function?

Tags: c++, pure-virtual

I tried to "repair" the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/99622/2932052) as to demonstrate how a pure virtual function can be called.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int id;
public:
    A(int i): id(i) {}
    int callFoo() { return foo(); }
    virtual int foo() = 0;
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    B(): A(callFoo()) {}
    int foo() { return 3; }
};

int main() {
    B b; // <-- this should call a pure virtual function
    cout << b.callFoo() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But I get no runtime error [here (with C++ 4.9.2)](https://ideone.com/Q3TNky), but the output 3. I tried the same with Borland C++ 5.6.4, but there I'm getting an access violation. I think that `foo()` should be pure virtual in the call of the constructor of the base class.

Who is wrong? Should I try more compilers? Am I right in my understanding of virtual functions?

Comment: I wouldn't use the results of a test with Borland C++ to see if a snippet of code is valid and/or compliant with the standard ;)

Comment: I think you are dancing with undefined behavior.  If you look at [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29365842cf9ff882) I get a segmentation fault when adding a `cout` statement to `A::callFoo()`.  If we remove the `cout` statement then it compiles and works.  I would have to guess that the minimal example just happens to work as the pointers stay aligned.

Comment: for anybody wondering, adding `A *a = new B;` gives a runtime error https://ideone.com/RV8mP8

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code has Undefined Behaviour: it is UB to call a member function on an object (even a non-virtual one) before all of its base classes have been initialised. C++14 (n4140) 12.6.2/14, emphasis mine:

> Member functions (including virtual member functions, 10.3) can be called for an object under construction.
>   Similarly, an object under construction can be the operand of the `typeid` operator (5.2.8) or of a `dynamic_cast` (5.2.7). **However, if these operations are performed in a *ctor-initializer* (or in a function called directly
>   or indirectly from a *ctor-initializer*) before all the *mem-initializers* for base classes have completed, the result
>   of the operation is undefined.** ...

*ctor-initializer* is the entire list following `:`. *mem-initializer* is one element of this list.

Comment: True and this UB rule is well-founded. But this only moves the headache - no compiler nor static code checker will find all errors. I was shocked that such simple inline cases didn't get instantly rejected.

Comment: @Wolf: The compiler [is not required to perform a full control-flow analysis](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/10/11/10455907.aspx), because that might not be possible to do statically at compile time.

Comment: @Kevin Implementing pure virtual functions to get rid of *pure virtual function called* messages seems like misuse to me, or was it designed for exactly this purpose?

Comment: @Wolf: I'm not advocating the fix discussed in that post, I just thought it contained some interesting information.  I'd be wary of implementing a pure virtual function because it would likely confuse someone.

Answer (score 5):

The statement `B b;` calls the default constructor to `B`.

When constructing `B`, nothing pertinent to `B` is constructed until `A` is fully constructed.

So in attempting to call `callFoo()`, the behaviour is undefined since you cannot rely on the v-table for class `B` being set up.

In summary: the behaviour of calling a pure virtual function during the construction of an abstract class is undefined.

Comment: I guessed this would be the case because. So, it seems I was a bit to lazy with my "repair" suggestion.