# Overload operator < in super class using pure virtual methods

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a hierarchy of `Figure` as base class and several sub classes `Circle`, `Square`, ecc. I want to overload `<` operator in `Figure` to sort Figures by eg. `Surface` which is implemented in base classes.

This is my code:

```
//Figure.hpp
class Figure
{
public:
    virtual float surface() const = 0;
    virtual float perimeter() const = 0;

    friend bool operator<(const Figure& lhs, const Figure& rhs);
    friend bool operator>=(const Figure& lhs, const Figure& rhs);
}

//Figure.cpp
bool operator<(const Figure& lhs, const Figure& rhs)
{
    return lhs.surface() < rhs.surface();
}

bool operator>=(const Figure& lhs, const Figure& rhs)
{
    return lhs.surface() >= rhs.surface();
}

//Square.hpp
class Square : public Figure{
public:
    Square(float size);
    float surface() const{
        return mSize * mSize;
    };
    float perimeter()const{
        return mSize * 4;
    }
private:
    float mSize;
};
```

Problem is I get an error at runtime:

```
libc++abi.dylib: Pure virtual function called!
```

at `lhs.surface()`.

I call the `<` operator in a `LinkedList` with `Template`:

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::insertNewNode(T& dataIn) 
{
    if(isEmpty()) 
    {
        insertBegin(dataIn);
    }else //otherwise
    {
        if(dataIn < *startPtr->data) 
        {
            insertBegin(dataIn);
        }
        else if(dataIn >= *endPtr->data) /
        {
            insertEnd(dataIn);
        }
        else 
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}

//main.cpp
List<Figure> *list = new List<Figure>();
Figure *square = new Square(46);
list->insertNewNode(*square);
```

**EDIT**
https://github.com/sanandrea/GenericLinkedList

Is this feasible or I am doing everything wrong?

Comment: Can you show some code that calls either operator? You aren't doing it in Square's constructor or destructor, right?

Comment: Cannot reproduce / not real code / does not compile and link. In any case, it's typically a bad idea to add operator overloading to OOP classes (i.e. classes with virtual functions), whose instances are often accessed via pointers or smart pointers. Your classes should either not have overloaded operators or not have virtual functions.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051749/how-to-track-down-libcabi-dylib-pure-virtual-function-called-in-xcode) might be related. But the originally posted code seems ok in general as it works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9180b852babf66c6) with minor modifications.

Comment: Could you post a complete single program that generates the error? My guess is that as you put the various elements together to create an [mcve](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you will probably find the problem.

Comment: So, in theory it is feasible?

Comment: By the way, you still have object slicing here: `T ListNode<T>::getData() ` in ListNode.hpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is both [Object Slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) and undefined behavior.

You insert values via

```
void List<T>::insertNewNode(T& dataIn)
```

which is OK. Since you pass it by reference the polymorphism will be kept. However, when you later call `insertBegin` or `insertEnd` to actually create the node you pass it by `T`:

```
void List<T>::insertBegin(T dataIn)
```

Here `dataIn` have lost the polymorphism due to Object Slicing. You also have undefined behavior when you store a pointer to the parameter in the newly created node:

```
ListNode<T> * newPtr = new ListNode<T>(&dataIn); //creates new node
```

Note that `&dataIn` is a pointer to the parameter of `insertBegin`, not a pointer to the `dataIn` that was passed in `insertNewNode(T& dataIn)`.

You also have Object Slicing in your node: `T ListNode<T>::getData() //returns data stored in node`.

Comment: Yep, they are stores as T*. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Sanan  Not in the code you posted. This `list->insertNewNode(*square);` would insert a Figure into the list, not a Square.

Comment: @latedeveloper You can't see how they are stored in his code...?

Comment: @gurka `List<Figure> *list = new List<Figure>();`

Comment: @latedeveloper https://github.com/sanandrea/GenericLinkedList/blob/master/GenericLinkedList/ListNode.hpp He stores them as T*. (`T* data;`)

Comment: @Sanandrea See Edit2.

Comment: Thank you! Here are the working changes! https://github.com/sanandrea/GenericLinkedList/commit/15dcfae5b4ff8c9c1ac93c76005b7d86d9352b90