# C++ pure virtual function call doesn't throw run-time exception?

Tags: c++, function, call, virtual, pure-virtual

It's said that in C++ constructor function, as long as the object has not finished construction, shouldn't call virtual function, or else there'll be "pure virtual function call error" thrown out. So I tried this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
class A{
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class A1 : public A{
public:
    void f(){printf("virtual function");}
    A1(){f();}
};
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    A1 a;
    return 0;
}
```

compile it with g++ on windows, it works and prints

```
virtual function
```

So how to make my program throw out "pure virtual function call" exception?

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious... can you link where this is said?
"It's said that in C++ constructor function, as long as the object has not finished construction, shouldn't call virtual function, or else there'll be "pure virtual function call error" thrown out. "

Comment: As far as I know there's no such exception in the C++ standard. This is a diagnosis crash message of msvc. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99552/where-do-pure-virtual-function-call-crashes-come-from, it describes when such messages can occur. I would vote to close the question as a duplicate of this link.

Comment: The road to hell is paved with virtual functions calls in constructors

Comment: You've probably gotten the rule wrong. The constructor will call the most inherited virtual up to the level of the class being constructed, but won't go any deeper. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45832805/4885321

Comment: Calling a virtual function in a constructor does not result in any exception.   The behaviour you are seeing (calling `A1::f()` since that is the most derived version of `f()` for class `A1`) is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not getting the "pure virtual method call" exception because `A::f()` is not being called.

`A1`'s constructor is calling its own `A1::f()` method, which is perfectly safe to do during `A1`'s construction.

The issue with calling a virtual method in a constructor has to do with a *base class* constructor calling a *derived class* method, which doesn't work since the derived portion of the object being constructed doesn't exist yet.

So, to get the exception you want, you need to call `f()` in `A`'s constructor rather than in `A1`'s constructor.